# JavaScript: Diference in sorting behavior array of objects with keys by object property

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have two arrays with the same information but different keys.

The keys of the first array are strings:

```
var myArray=[];

myArray["Bob"]={Name: "Bob", Age:21};
myArray["Steve"]={Name: "Steve", Age:30};
myArray["Tony"]={Name: "Tony", Age:11};
```

The second array is indexed normally:

```
var myOtherArray=[];

myOtherArray.push({Name: "Bob", Age:21});
myOtherArray.push({Name: "Steve", Age:30});
myOtherArray.push({Name: "Tony", Age:11});
```

If I try to sort them by age:

```
myArray.sort(({Age:b}, {Age:a}) => a-b)
myOtherArray.sort(({Age:b}, {Age:a}) => a-b)
```

In the end myOtherArray will be sorted but myArray will remain sorted by key. What am I missing here?
Thanks!

Comment: `myArray` doesn't actually have any elements, so you're not sorting anything. (It has values held under string keys, but those aren't elements of the array.) Note that objects have no ordering of their string keys, ordering only applies to arrays and their numeric indices.

Comment: Object order is defined and standardized, but it is the order they have been added. 

To explain the problem, you must understand that Array extends Object. To save value in array and not its parent object Object, you must use numeric key.

Comment: Array methods (like `sort`) work only on array *indexes*, not other properties. This is intended behaviour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first array does not actually contain any elements; you are treating it like an object by setting properties on it, which are ordered in insertion order except for numeric keys which are ordered in ascending order.

You used the standard push method to add to the second array, so it works.